# ASP.NET MVC website route map not working

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

In my ASP.NET MVC website, I want to route

p/this-is-some-dynamic-text-and-delimited-by-hyphen/2086

to

myarea/profile/detail/2086

Basically, I want to use the letter p and the id number to display the profile, so i will ignore the area and whatever text in between p and id.

I have an Area called 'Myarea', and the controller is: Profile, action is Detail.
How do I setup the route map? here is what I tried, but not working:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Pa Profile",
    url: "p/{text}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by moving the maproute code to area register function:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {}
```